Zero Bytes After Modbus Function 0x0B, 0x0C Requests
I'm analyzing pcap file with Modbus traffic and noticed something unexpected. In the requests for Modbus functions 0x0B (Get Comm Event Log) and 0x0C (Get Comm Event Counter), there are 4 null bytes immediately following the function code, even though the Modbus specification indicates that there should be no additional data following the function code.
Here is an example of the raw data:
0B 00 00 00 00 ...
0C 00 00 00 00 ...
Has anyone encountered this before? Could this be an implementation-specific detail, or am I missing something in the specification?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
wireshark pic

Are you sure this is a request and not a response?
A Get Comm Event Counter response could look exactly like your capture, there is a 2-byte 'Status' field followed by a 2-byte 'Event Count' field.
However, what's missing, whether this is a response or not, is a valid CRC. So it's also possible you're just dealing with a buggy implementation.
edit: also, I can't tell from just your screenshot, but if that's a MBAP header in the preceding bytes and this is Modbus TCP and not Modbus RTU-over-TCP, then you're dealing with something extra f*cked because 0x0B and 0x0C are for serial lines only. It might explain the missing CRC though.

Yes, I also noticed that these functions are only for Serial; however, they appear in the traffic, just like the Server_ID functions, even though it is also only for Serial. I am inclined to think that this is a faulty implementation, but I would like confirmation of this. Is it possible that there is traffic with 0x0B 0x0C without padding bytes?
